# Reshaping a numpy array with 1 value left over

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to reshape an array of length 179 into a 9 x 20 arrays using reshape, how can I do 8 of 20 and 1 of 19?

```
lst2 = np.array(np.random.rand(180))
lst2.reshape(9, 20)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 179 into shape (9,20)
```

Comment: Regards @thomas.mac . Why don't you add one dummy value (or a `None`) to the end of `lst2` so that it can be reshaped with size 9x20. This `None` would be at 9th row and 20th column of your array

Comment: i was trying to find the sum of each array... but just restructured it to np.cumsum(lst[::20])

Comment: this helps for future reference though, thanks

Comment: Don't use a Python object like `None` as dummy value. This will either cause an error or lead to the creation of a horribly inefficient object-typed array.

Answer (score 0):

`np.array(random.rand(180))` creates an array of length 180. So `lst2.reshape(9,20)` works great.

If you want to reshape to 8 x 20, it means you should delete some data (20 values) like in the following:

```
lst[0:-20].reshape(8,20)
```